# Getting only partial HTML when using sockets in python

Tags: python, html, sockets, httprequest

i've been tasked with using sockets in python to grab the HTML from a site.
So far, this is what i've come up with.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
hostName = socket.gethostbyname('www.usask.ca')
print(hostName)
s.connect((hostName, 80))
s.send("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: " + hostName + "\r\n\r\n")
print (s.recv(500000000))
s.close
```

It doesn't work very well. I'm less concerned with the robustness of it (I think it's a problem of the request formatting) and more concerned with it only printing a small fraction of the html when it does work.

When using something like urlib2 to get the html it seems by comparison, that i'm only getting at most 10% of what I want.

Comment: The website you're trying to load is rejecting your request with a 403 Forbidden error. This code works fine for other websites.

Comment: @Rawing When I try it with arguments like "www.google.ca" or "www.google.com" for example, I get 301 error codes, where those same passed arguments with a urlib2 approach work perfectly